# How to set HIVE properties while loading data from HIVE to HIVE in ODI

Tags: oracle, hive, oracle-data-integrator

You can set different properties before querying in HIVE for example:

- set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce=false;
- set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;

But I want to set these properties while loading data in ODI, please note that in my case source and target is HIVE. however, these properties can be added while loading data from Oracle to HIVE.

Comment: IF you set " set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce=false;"  from beeline , it will be set only for the connection ( and you just have to add the properties  to your sql code )  , but if you set the propriety in hive-site.xml , you don't need to set it each time ( just run your code)

Comment: I need to set it from ODI, from beeline or HUE it's working fine but problem is while running from ODI.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can write those commands in the topology section, like indicated below. I need to be sincerely and tell you that I didn't tried but as I read, it should work.

> ODI > Topology > Physical Architecture > Hive > Source Data Server >
>   On Connect/Disconnect > On Connect > Command: **write down your commands.**

[image]